# issue logout because AntiForgeryToken not passing to controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create logout function but for some reason my AntiForgeryToken is failing to pass back to controller class. I am using MVC4. I am using SimpleMembership.

here is my code.

### razar code

```
 <div id="loginBar">
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>

        Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Account");
        {
             @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
             @Html.ActionLink("Log-Out", "LogOut", "Account")
         }            
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Register Me", "Registration", "Account")
        <span> | </span>
        @Html.ActionLink("Log In", "LogIn", "Account")
    }
</div>
```

### Account Controller class

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        WebSecurity.Logout();


        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

LogOut is a Post Method. Thats why you getting this error. The `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` is expected as posted data into the request. Change the method to `HttpPost`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`<input type="submit" value="logout" />`

and
`@using(Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Account")){
...
}`

so the data will actually be submitted to the Controller.
If you want to keep a text link, you could use jQuery to submit à la

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Account", new {id= "myForm"})
{
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="logoutText">logout</a>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#logoutText').click(function(){
        $('#myForm').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i can use logout on its own ... my issue is i need to send @Html.AntiForgeryToken along with post request

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not even need **Form** for **ActionLink** which renders as a hyper link.

Second, you should not validate **AntiForgeryToken** for get method.

### Just replace

```
Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Account");
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ActionLink("Log-Out", "LogOut", "Account")
}
```

### with

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log-Out", "LogOut", "Account")
```

Comment: i have used initially which works fine, but i need to send AntiForgeryToken in post form!!!

Comment: You are not posting anything in your code; why do you need `AntiForgeryToken` for? If you view **Page Source**, **Log-Out** is just a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code

```
Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Account");
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.ActionLink("Log-Out", "LogOut", "Account")
}
```

with

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
}
```

and 
    [HttpGet]
to
    [HttpPost]
in your Controller's Action